# VS2008 Debugger Hang

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Team System with SP1, and I've noticed an annoying tendency for the IDE to hang for several (10-15) seconds whenever I stop debugging an application.  At first I thought this only happened with WPF apps, but I've observed the behavior in Windows Forms apps and ASP.NET sites as well.  I've made a series of changes to the Options based on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) and done exhaustive Google/MSDN searches, but still haven't found a way to stop this.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

@[korona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25731/korona) - Nope, that didn't fix it.  Thanks for your suggestion, though.

More research in ProcMon shows this interesting tidbit, not sure if it is related:

```
8:45:46.6790857 AM  WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe 7684    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\WINXP\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\enterprisesec.config.cch FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 48, Length: 12
8:45:46.6793569 AM  WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe 7684    ReadFile    C:\WINXP\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\enterprisesec.config.cch FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 508, Length: 12
```

This repeats several times, like hundreds of times, then it switches to a different path:

```
8:45:46.7470314 AM  WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe 7684    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    D:\documents and settings\myusername\Application Data\Microsoft\CLR Security Config\v2.0.50727.42\security.config.cch   FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 48, Length: 12
8:45:46.7472187 AM  WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe 7684    ReadFile    D:\documents and settings\myusername\Application Data\Microsoft\CLR Security Config\v2.0.50727.42\security.config.cch   FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 508, Length: 12
```

And repeats again many more times, with slight changes in the offset each iteration.  Maybe unrelated, but....

Comment: I see the same thing for Smart Device applications, so it's not just you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your ProcMon results, it appears that it's that CreateFile() call that's taking all the time.  I'm assuming that all activity is waiting for that thread to return.  You can verify this -- with some difficulty -- in Process Explorer (also part of the SysInternals package previously linked), using the Threads tab on the Properties window.

So, if CreateFile is what's causing the blockage, that would suggest that it's a delay in Windows itself.   What Pierre said -- look out for network shares -- was my first instinct, too.  I've had a lot of seemingly-inexplicable slowdowns in the past when Explorer had a mapping to a share that I couldn't currently reach, even though I wasn't doing any work on those shares at the time.

Can you test this possibility by unmapping all your drives and unplugging from the network?  Is D: a separate physical drive from C:?  If so, see if it goes faster if you move your build directory to C:.

Answer (score 2):

I observed this kind of behaviour on one of my development machines and Visual Studio 2005. The problem was caused by Visual Studio trying to reach some non existent network share (I don't remember exactly why). You could give [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) a try in order to see if your Visual Studio is trying to do something silly when finishing debugging and returning to the normal view. Maybe because you have some broken plug-in in some tool bar or in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Bingo!  It's something to do with a network share.  I don't know which one yet, but it should be pretty easy to figure out now that I know where to look.  I took your advice, unhooked my NIC, disconnected my network drives, and re-ran.  No hang!  Thank you so, so much.  This will make life much better.

Answer (score 1):

From the site below I found several possible solutions.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/e9c5da47-a194-4051-a3d5-28b404263b3f

The one that worked best was to run Internet Explorer
Then go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Security section, uncheck "Check for Publisher's Certificate Revocation"

Comment: None of the solutions on that link worked for me :( and VS2008 is hanging for 2-3 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Does it hangover even with basic apps?  Like making a new windows form then hitting debug, or is it only with more complicated apps?  Because I've noticed that before too (maybe not quite 10-15 seconds, but there has been a bit of a lag that I've noticed) but when I just tried debugging a relatively simple windows form app, I didn't get it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I created a very simple Windows Forms app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I am saying hello.");
}
```

Still hangs a good 10 seconds on closing the form.

Comment: i assume that your system resources are sufficient? ie Ram etc

Comment: They should be fine, I think.  Core2 Duo 2.33, 3.25 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

@[Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4597/pierre) - I ran ProcMon on devenv.exe and timed the application close.  The results are interesting.  It hung for 15 seconds, and you can see the hang in ProcMon.  From 8:45:31 to 8:45:46, there isn't any activity recorded.  I'm going to mess around with the filter in ProcMon and see if it's something outside of devenv.exe, but here's what I recorded from devenv.exe around the 15 second span:

```
8:45:31.0221244 AM  devenv.exe  7096    QueryNameInformationFile    D:\Working\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe  BUFFER OVERFLOW Name: \W
8:45:31.0227991 AM  devenv.exe  7096    CreateFile  D:\Working\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe.Manifest NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read/Execute, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
8:45:46.7647624 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{141243A4-76E6-4FC3-A114-EAE02389304E}  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.7647792 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{141243A4-76E6-4FC3-A114-EAE02389304E}   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.7649139 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{141243A4-76E6-4FC3-A114-EAE02389304E}  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.7649264 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{141243A4-76E6-4FC3-A114-EAE02389304E}   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9834610 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\UseMRUDocOrdering  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
8:45:46.9835087 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\UseMRUDocOrdering  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
8:45:46.9865681 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveLeft  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9865881 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveLeft   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9866155 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveLeft  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9866285 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveLeft   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9869661 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveRight NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9869813 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveRight  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9870055 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveRight NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9870177 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveRight  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9872667 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9872818 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9873078 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9873207 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9875683 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9875873 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9876141 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9876276 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9912375 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TreatAs  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
8:45:46.9912529 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TreatAs   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
8:45:46.9914799 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Managed\S-1-5-21-2966119792-2635991036-4117835597-414090\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9915751 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Managed\S-1-5-21-2966119792-2635991036-4117835597-414090\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9916485 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegEnumValue    HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860 NO MORE ENTRIES Index: 1, Length: 220
8:45:46.9916921 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\AppMgmt\{B72DC9F7-717F-48A3-A281-F5187E018006}  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
8:45:46.9917220 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Managed\S-1-5-21-2966119792-2635991036-4117835597-414090\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9918086 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Managed\S-1-5-21-2966119792-2635991036-4117835597-414090\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
8:45:46.9918661 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegEnumValue    HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Features\7F9CD27BF7173A842A185F81E7100860 NO MORE ENTRIES Index: 1, Length: 220
8:45:46.9919019 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9919204 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9919447 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocHandler32  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9919595 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocHandler32   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9919825 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocHandlerX86 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9919969 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocHandlerX86  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9920191 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9920322 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9920543 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9920677 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9921310 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\AppID    NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
8:45:46.9921387 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCR\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\AppID NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
8:45:46.9921910 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\ProxyStubClsid32 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
8:45:46.9922398 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\ProxyStubClsid32 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9922774 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\ProxyStubClsid32 NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9923306 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\Forward  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
8:45:46.9923447 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCR\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\Forward   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
8:45:46.9923676 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\TypeLib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9924159 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\TypeLib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9924549 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\TypeLib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9924925 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\TypeLib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9925301 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\Interface\{A6FAF38C-284B-48B3-B871-84B9A66010E9}\TypeLib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9925761 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9926243 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9926490 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegEnumKey  HKCR\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A} NO MORE ENTRIES Index: 1, Length: 288
8:45:46.9926676 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9927153 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9927525 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9928018 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0\win32    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9928530 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0\win32    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9928710 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCR\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0\win32\(Default)   BUFFER OVERFLOW Length: 144
8:45:46.9928986 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0\win32    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
8:45:46.9929159 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegQueryValue   HKCR\TypeLib\{95FF4B0C-E6EC-470C-82AC-EB0471714C5A}\1.0\0\win32\(Default)   BUFFER OVERFLOW Length: 144
8:45:46.9936201 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 224, Length: 4
8:45:46.9936267 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 224, Length: 4
8:45:46.9938304 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 228, Length: 20
8:45:46.9938360 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 228, Length: 20
8:45:46.9939826 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 472, Length: 40
8:45:46.9939877 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 472, Length: 40
8:45:46.9941335 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 512, Length: 40
8:45:46.9941384 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 512, Length: 40
8:45:46.9943155 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 552, Length: 40
8:45:46.9943207 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 552, Length: 40
8:45:46.9944710 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,072, Length: 16
8:45:46.9944762 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,072, Length: 16
8:45:46.9947328 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,088, Length: 8
8:45:46.9947380 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,088, Length: 8
8:45:46.9948846 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,232, Length: 2
8:45:46.9948895 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,232, Length: 2
8:45:46.9954480 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,234, Length: 14
8:45:46.9954536 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,234, Length: 14
8:45:46.9956052 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,104, Length: 16
8:45:46.9956103 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,104, Length: 16
8:45:46.9957616 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,120, Length: 8
8:45:46.9957666 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,120, Length: 8
8:45:46.9959108 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,152, Length: 16
8:45:46.9959158 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,152, Length: 16
8:45:46.9961043 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,168, Length: 8
8:45:46.9961095 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,168, Length: 8
8:45:46.9962559 AM  devenv.exe  7096    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Offset: 3,200, Length: 16
8:45:46.9962612 AM  devenv.exe  7096    FASTIO_CHECK_IF_POSSIBLE    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSENV\vsprojhostproc.olb FAST IO DISALLOWED  Operation: Read, Offset: 3,200, Length: 16
8:45:47.0162060 AM  devenv.exe  7096    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TreatAs  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it's the same problem, but I've had VC++ behave in a similar manner during debugging. This mostly happened when breaking into a crashed program though, so once again I'm not sure if it's the same issue but it might be worth a try.

The reason:
The debugged process dies while having locks acquired on mutexes that Text Services Framework uses to render text. When other apps try to render any text they end up being deadlocked until the debugged process dies.

The fix:
Turn off advanced text services by opening Control Panel, Regional and Language Options, Languages, Details..., Advanced and checking the box labeled "Turn off advanced text services".

Sorry if this is unrelated to your problem, but it sure has helped me with my debugger acting up and locking my system.

More information: http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=118

Answer (score 0):

Great, as in my case, then. Have you been able to find out what network share Visual Studio was trying to access. You might want to try [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to investigate further. You'll see what traffic your PC is generating...