# Visual Studio 2008 hangs every few minutes for over a minute

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 (VS2008 version 9 SP1 on Windows Vista) hangs/freezes every few minutes for over a minute ( sometimes up to 5 minutes ). I can access other parts of the computer while vs2008 is busy. This happened for a few days in January 2013 and about a week ago and now it is happening again.

At first I thought this only happened while debugging so I tried most if not all of the things in these posts:

- [VS2008 Debugger Hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198979/vs2008-debugger-hang)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e9c5da47-a194-4051-a3d5-28b404263b3f

I thought it had something to do with breakpoints because it seemed to happen when adding/removing breakpoints:

- [Visual Studio freezes on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817287/visual-studio-freezes-on-breakpoints)

It happens with all breakpoints removed and the program not even running, albeit less often. I can sometimes get this hang to occur by doing nothing with vs2008 other than re-focusing it or scrolling up and down in a .cs file. Speaking of that, it only seems to happen on large files 5000+ lines. I have not replicated the issue on files with say 3000 lines.

I tried deleting .suo file, bin and obj folders, updating everything, rolling back updates, virus scan, spyware scan, memory test, disabling addins, deactivate vs2008 host process, disabling nic, unplugging ethernet, modifying hosts file with 127.0.0.1 crl.microsoft.com and 127.0.0.1 6to4.ipv6.microsoft.com.

As far as the comments about Process Monitor and CreateFile, I had some logs the other day that said something about CreateFile and the result was something other than SUCCESS but today all CreateFile results are SUCCESS.

I have DevExpress controls installed. Since it seems to only happen on larger files I figured it might be a code parsing problem and found several things to disable in the DevExpress options. The hanging seems to happen less often but it still happens.

Any other Ideas/Solutions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

More related links:

- [Visual Studio 2008 Constantly Freezes on Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994364/visual-studio-2008-constantly-freezes-on-me)

**Update:**

I have a ton of these in ProcMon: CreateFile, QueryNetworkOpenInformationFile and CloseFile for
C:\Program Files\DevExpress 2011.2\IDETools\System\CodeRush\BIN\PLUGINS\CR_SmartPaste.dll

So I decided to disable CodeRush completely using directions from this link: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q393455.aspx

So far things seem to be working great....Gotta love solving a question right after posting it... I will leave it for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal solution was to disable CodeRush by following the directions at this link: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q393455.aspx

I just remembered that when I had this problem in the past I disabled a small portion of the CodeRush features. It might be too soon to tell if this will be a good solution.

**Edit:**
After disabling CodeRush I had other, different, hanging/freezing issues that were fixed by deleting the .SUO file ( again ) and clearing the obj and bin folders.

After those issues were fixed I was suddenly unable to build in release mode...lol... but that issue seems to have gone away... the last thing I did was to disable all norton protection and restart my computer. I restarted b/c norton crashed when I manually disabled each item so I was unable to access the management window. I restarted the computer several other times during this ordeal so I do not think that was the issue alone. I have the latest version of norton as of 26Mar2013 and it was recently updated so I figured that maybe the new version was affecting vs2008.

I am on vista but this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/12/16/how-to-solve-visual-studio-hang-problem-when-working-in-win7-with-norton-antivirus.aspx might help someone on win7 with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Was suffering a lot with whole Studio UI constantly freezes.
I used to hover my mouse over buttons in a toolbars, that caused UI to refresh.
Then i found a permanent solution, while was experimenting with different settings.

Try
Tools - Options - Environment - General
"Visual experience" group
Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" (required for the next step).
Then uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration"

Works for me.
Good luck